# cannot retrieve user profile picture Parse iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Im having problem with this line

`let userImageFile:PFFile = user["photo"] as PFFile`

code doesnt go beyond from this line. i tried searching everywhere in internet. but couldn't understand the error. in my below code im always getting "Something error". but my username retrieve works fine.

```
    var user = spread.objectForKey("spreader") as! PFUser

    user.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock { (obj: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if obj != nil {
            var fetchedUser = obj as! PFUser
            var username = fetchedUser["username"] as! String
            cell.username.text = user.username

            //Profile Picture Retrieve

    if let userImageFile:PFFile = user["photo"] as? PFFile{ 
       println("working")
        userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                if imageData != nil{
                    cell.profileImage.image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                }else{
                    println("No Data")
                }

            }else{
                println(error)
            }
        }

    }else{

        println("Something Error") // Always getting this

    }



        }
    }




    return cell
}
```

[image]

Comment: so you can not see working print out on console, if not it means user["phot"] returns nil and in that case it will never go inside loop

Comment: yes thats the problem. i cant understand why its not going inside that loop. that is the default structure in every guide and documents in the internet. :(

Comment: can you print user in console and see what it has

Comment: and to make sure you have full data for user just do [user fetch] before if statement, that will fetch latest data

Comment: i just add `println(user)` before the `//Profile Picture Retrieve` part. and got this . i think its working fine. <PFUser: 0x14681390, objectId: AUQo5tmG8t, localId: (null)> {
    email = "myemail@outlook.com";
    emailVerified = 1;
    username = cadelewis;
}

Comment: but there is no photo in that object, so that's why its not going in the loop

Comment: hmm yes i can see it. but why. photo column is always in parse table. ill update the screenshot

Comment: Oh i found the error. `cadelewis` profile i added the image manually. but i tried other account that i upload image using app. then it worked. thank you for help